# Get 0 rows from ARRAY_GET with null array

Tags: arrays, h2

Can I filter to get an empty result set when using `ARRAY_AGG` with a null array?

Tried various queries:

```sql
DROP TABLE test IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE test (arr INT ARRAY);
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(arr) FROM test;
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(arr) FROM test WHERE arr IS NOT NULL;
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(arr) FILTER (WHERE arr IS NOT NULL) FROM test;
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(arr) FILTER (WHERE arr IS NOT NULL) FROM test WHERE arr IS NOT NULL;
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(arr) FROM test WHERE CARDINALITY(arr) > 0;
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(arr) FROM test WHERE NOT(ARRAY_CONTAINS(arr, NULL));
```

but all return 1 row with null, and I want 0 rows

```sql
null
(1 row, 0 ms)
```

I'm probably missing something obvious...

Comment: FWIW, this behavior is consistent with how other SQL aggregates work.

Comment: Can you handle this at the application level?

Comment: Hm, okay, yes, I can handle it in my application. Would just have been nice not to have to. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a wrong filtration clause. If you want to return 0 rows from an aggregated query, you can do it with the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(arr) FROM test HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

But if you want to get an empty array instead, you can use `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(ARRAY_AGG(arr), ARRAY[]) FROM test;
```

Comment: Thanks, Evgenij! `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` did the trick for me.